# No scroll bar on mobile when html content are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am building a responsive website where majority of its content are created on client's end. The original HTML is rather small and 'short', however as content is created and added the overall height of the application grows.

The issue I'm facing right now is that on mobile devices, (iphone, ipad, Windows phone, etc) the browser doesn't recognize the fact that the page is growing, so no vertical scroll bar is created as contents grow.

Some awkward scrolling is possible on iOS devices, but on windows phones, from what I've heard there is no scrolling.

How can I fix this? I was thinking of setting a minimum height for my html body. Is there anything else?

Here is a screenshot, as you can see there is no vertical scroll bar, even though the page is fairly long. 
[image]

The site is up on http://jobtorch.net/ right now.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't _show_ a scrollbar? On iOS and Android the scrollbar doesn't display until the user starts scrolling. Are you saying the page itself doesn't scroll?

Comment: @adamb No scrollbar is shown when user scrolls the page. The scrolling is also awkward and inconsistent with how safari usually scrolls on ios devices.

Comment: in my samsung galaxy Y happen it too. are you using bootstrap correct?

Comment: Check if you have event.preventDefault() in your script anywhere

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves There is no call to event.preventDefault() in any of my scripts or scripts included with the website.

Comment: overflow:scroll not supported in android<4 so check if you have used it in div structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` of your page is not inheriting the height of your `.maincontent` div, because you're using absolute positioning on said div. (the height of `body` is what mobile browsers use to identify "page" scrolling.)

Remove `position: absolute;` from your CSS for `.maincontent`, and you should be fine.